# MySQL JOIN from one of the two table based on IF condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-view

```
SELECT Table1.Filter, Table1.Condition, Combined.Data FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Key, Data FROM IF(Table1.Filter, Table2, Table3))) AS Combined 
ON Table1.Condition = Combined.Key
```

I want to create a MySQL View that shows all columns of `Table1`, and a column from either `Table2` or `Table3` depending on the field on `Table1.Filter`.

One simple solution is to `LEFT JOIN` both `Table2` and `Table3`, with `NULL` on the column that is not applicable. Is there a way to avoid creating 2 columns?
I cannot `UNION` `Table2` and `Table3` as they might contain the same `Key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
SELECT t1.Filter, t1.Condition,
       COALESCE(t2.Data, t3.Data) as Data
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.Filter AND t2.Key = t1.Condition LEFT JOIN
     Table3 t3
     ON (NOT t1.Filter) AND t3.key = t1.condition;
```

You cannot have conditionals choosing tables in the `FROM`.  But, you can have conditions in the `ON` conditions.